# Why is my Python code returning an error when I try to fetch YouTube videos for a given keyword?

Tags: python-2.7, youtube, youtube-api

Whenever I try to run my code, I receive the following error: "comment_content error! 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'href'" I am new to Python, and did not write this code myself; it was given to me to use. My understanding is that it was functioning properly before? Could this have to do with changes in the YouTube Data API since it was written?

```
import pdb
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import codecs
import time

client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()


### the input words are here
query.vq = "4b hair"
#######

# the out put file are here
viewFile = codecs.open('views4b_hair.csv', 'w')
commentFile=codecs.open('comments4b_hair.csv', 'w')
##########



query.max_results = 50
query.start_index = 0
query.safesearch = "moderate"
#query.format = 5
query.orderby = "relevance"
#query.author = "hawaiinani"
#pdb.set_trace() 




for i in range(19):
    #pdb.set_trace() 
    query.start_index=str(int(query.start_index)+50)
    feed = client.YouTubeQuery(query)
    print len(feed.entry)

    youtubeid=[]
    youtubetitle=[]
    for entry in feed.entry:

        #youtubetitle.append(entry.title.text)
        youtubeid.append(entry.id.text[38:])
        print entry.id.text[38:],i
        try:
           entry_comment = client.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=entry.id.text[38:])
           comment_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=entry.id.text[38:])            
           viewFile.write(','.join([entry.id.text[38:],entry_comment.published.text,
                               str(entry_comment.media.duration.seconds), str(entry_comment.statistics.view_count),comment_feed.total_results.text,entry_comment.media.title.text.decode('ascii', errors='ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore')]) + '\n')
            #videop.append("%s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"],entry.published.text,
            #                       entry.media.duration.seconds, entry.statistics.view_count,comment_feed.total_results.text,entry.media.title.text))
            #  
           #time.sleep(3)
        except Exception, ex:
            print 'View_content Error', ex
            time.sleep(10)
        try:
           comment_content = client.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=entry.id.text[38:])
           indexh=0
           #while comment_content:
           while indexh<10:
               indexh=indexh+1
               for comment_entry in comment_content.entry:
                   pubText = comment_entry.published.text
                   #print pubText

                   titleText = comment_entry.content.text.decode('ascii', errors='ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                   #print titleText
                   #print 'Got title'
                   #pubText, titleText = comment_entry.published.text, comment_entry.title.text
                   commentFile.write(','.join([entry.id.text[38:],pubText,titleText]) + '\n'+'\n')
                   #commentFile.write(u',')
                   #commentFile.write(pubText + u',')
                   #print 'About to write title'
                   #print titleText

                   #print 'Wrote title'

                   #commentlist.append("%s, %s,%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"],pubText, titleText)) 
               comment_content=client.Query(comment_content.GetNextLink().href)
               #time.sleep(3)
           #time.sleep(3)
        except Exception, ex:
            print 'Comment_content Error!', ex
            time.sleep(5)





    #pdb.set_trace()
viewFile.close()
commentFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when `comment_content.GetNextLink()` becomes `None`. In order to fix it, replace:

```
while indexh < 10:
```

with:

```
while indexh < 10 and comment_content:
```

also replace:

```
comment_content=client.Query(comment_content.GetNextLink().href)
```

with:

```
next_link = comment_content.GetNextLink()
if next_link:
    comment_content = client.Query(next_link.href)
else:
    comment_content = None
```

Hope that helps.